# Certain key doesn't work when pressed, only when held

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

After swapping my language and input options about (UK layout and German layout) to support the two keyboards I have, a certain key will stop working partially depending on the layout.

If I swap my input method to UK, the apostrophe/at-sign key will stop working. Windows 10 will make a tone sound when pressed twice, and if held it will input many of that key, as should be the case.

If I swap the the DE layout, the would-be apostrophe key works fine, but the colon/semicolon key (Ö on the German keyboard) stops working unless held.

I'm certain it's not a hardware issue, it must be to do with Windows 10.
What's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: This is indeed not a hardware issue, but in fact the way these keyboard layouts work. Those keys that stop working become modifier keys and if you type them, followed by a space, you get their normal key. If you type them, followed by another letter, depending on what letter you type, it will modify that letter. '+e = é for example. So the solution is to find a better input type that suits your needs. I usually use US Standard if I don't want any fancy characters, and US International if I want basic support for modifiers.

Comment: I don't know what keyboard you have, so that's why I posted this as comments and not an answer with a suggestion for the right keyboard layout.

Comment: This isn't the case with mine; typing an apostrophe followed by any vowel or space doesn't do anything but make a vague Windows tone sound. It also wouldn't explain the Ö key not working the same on the German layout.

Comment: Trust me, its a keyboard layout issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by removing a mistakenly added 'change layout' shortcut, to the grave (`) key, oddly affecting the apostrophe and ö keys on the other layouts.

To fix this:

- Context-menu/Right-mouse on the Language Bar on the Windows taskbar
  -> Settings/Einstellungen
- In the third section, "Change the Input Method"/"Wechseln der ingabemethode", open the blue link at the bottom, "Change the shortcut keys for the Language    Bar"/"Abkürzungstasten der Sprachenleiste ändern"
- From there,
  remove the setting for "Change Input Language"/"Zwischen
  Eingabesprachen" from whatever it is (mine was Graviszeichen (`)) to
  None.

Answer (score 0):

This exact thing happened to me and this thread lead me to the answer.

The language bar, for whatever reason, wasn't present on my taskbar so I went into Windows 10 Settings/Time & Language/Region & language/Advanced Keyboard Settings/Language Bar Options.
In there I went to the Advanced Key Setting tab and selected "Change Key Sequence...". In the box that appeared I set both options to "Not Assigned" and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the exact same issue (`Ö` only working when held down) and I somehow stumbled across this question, so I wanted to post an answer with the current method to remove these shortcuts in Windows 10 version 2004:

- Go into Settings > Time & language > Language > Keyboard > Input language hot keys
- Select "Between input languages" then click "Change Key Sequence..." (even if it says "(none)" under "Key sequence" in the table it might still be assigned!)
- Make sure in the dialog that opens that none of them is set to "Grave Accent (`)".
  If it is, change it to "Not Assigned" and press OK.

Your `Ö` key should be back to functioning again

Answer (score 0):

Ditto here. I had exactly the same problem (Windows 10 home, version 1909) and, as with Local Crab Enthusiast, it occurred after I tweaked the custom keyboard shortcut to change the language (in my case so I could switch between a German and a Danish keyboard layout).

There's a good description of it (with illustrations) [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/keyboard-shortcut-to-change-the-language-on-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Advanced%20Key%20Settings%20tab%20and,keyboard%20shortcut%20to%20switch%20to%20a%20specific%20language.).

Now that I've made sure that “Switch Input Language” is set to “Not assigned,”  the "Ö" key is working perfectly again. It's such a relief to find out that my hardware is fine and it's just a Microsoft software glitch.

Thanks for your help, everyone!